# How to include an HTML button inside Laravel code

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a button if a condition is not true. In the code below I need to show the "follow group" button if the output is not true. It is working fine, but I don't know the syntax to put the button inside the Laravel code.

```php
{{ Auth::user()->grpusers()->where('group_id', $group->id)->first() == True ? 'You are following this group' :   <a href="{{ route('group.follow', ['id' =>$group->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Follow Group</a>     }}
```

Comment: just use if else here

Comment: I'm already using it, but how do I put the html button inside it ?

Comment: if it worked for you mark it as accepted answer so other can also get benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `if else`

```
<p> 
@if( Auth::user()->grpusers()->where('group_id', $group->id)->first() == True)
You are following this group
@else
<a href="{{ route('group.follow', ['id' =>$group->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Follow Group</a>
@endif
</p>
```